# Javascript - for loop printing only the last iteration

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

i'd like to print every iteration in my loop (1,2,3,4,5). But at this moment, it's only printing the size of my array (5).

```
for (var key in mapParseJson.background) {

  //sequelize
  refModelBedrawnins.find({
    where: ['POS_TILE_BE_DRAW_IN =? ',mapParseJson.background[key]            [0]],
    include: [{ model: refModelDrawableObject }]
  }).success(function(result) {

    // I'd like to print every iteration right here
    console.log(key);
  });

}
```

Comment: Show the entire code (i.e. the content of mapParseJson.background)

Comment: Are you seeing multiple `5`s or only one? (Note that some console will indicate identical repeat messages with a repeat counter to the left or right of the message.)

Comment: I'm seeing mutiple 5s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid the closure and save the var "key" value:

```
for (var key in mapParseJson.background) {
    //sequelize
    (function(k){
         refModelBedrawnins.find({ 
             where: ['POS_TILE_BE_DRAW_IN =? ', mapParseJson.background[k]            [0]],
             include: [{model: refModelDrawableObject}] 
         }).success(function(result) {
             console.log(k);
         });
    })(key);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but the function() isn't executed. (i'm using nodejs to print the result). If I console.log('test') in the anonymous function it's just printing nothing

Comment: i've edited, really sorry, I used to do it with functions ..